# polyline snap to roads in Bing Maps

Tags: maps, bing

I have almost the same question as here,
[Track a user draw polyline snap to roads bing maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419002/track-a-user-draw-polyline-snap-to-roads-bing-maps)

I don't find any javascipt API in the documentation for road snapping of a polyline.
There is a HTTP ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt814927.aspx ) but I would like to snap to road local data, as it would be done in the google maps API [polyline snap to road using google maps api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513360/polyline-snap-to-road-using-google-maps-api-v3)

So, is there a Bing API to snap polyline to road in a javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Open up Bing and put in "bing api road snap"

From that first result I get https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/snap-to-road

Comment: I know, you can see I have already mention it in the question. But this is a REST API, and a billable one. I'm looking for a javascript API to use on local data, with thousand of point.